# Why is the output of this code only taking 3 values of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to solve this issue for a long time now. What I'm trying to achieve is to print the `tableData` lists in a vertical way.

```
tableData = [["apples","oranges","cherries","banana"], ["Alice","Bob","Carol","David"],
             ["dogs","cats","moose","goose"]]

def printTable():
    for i in range(len(tableData)):
        for x in tableData:
            print(x[i], end = " ")
        print()

print(printTable())
```

For now I've achieved to print the following output:

```
apples Alice dogs
oranges Bob cats
cherries Carol moose
None
```

The problem is that the number [4] on the list doesn't print out and instead it prints `None`. I cann't think of what is the issue, as my thoughts behind it is that with the command `range(len(tableData))` I'm already using the whole list.

Comment: do you mean `print(*zip(*tableData))`?

Comment: maybe you want `range(len(tableData[0])`

Answer (score 2):

`i` is ranging over the length of `tableData` itself, not over the length of each *element* of `tableData`.

```
for i in range(len(tableData[0]))):
    for row in tableData:
        print(row[i], end=" ")
    print()
```

There's a simpler way to transpose a table, though: use `zip`.

```
for column in zip(*tableData):
    print(' '.join(column))
```

Comment: That should be `for i in range(len(tableData[0]))`

Comment: Actually I think it should be `for row in tableData:`, then `for item in row:`, then `print(item, end=" ")` to eliminate indexing altogether.

Comment: @martineau The `i`th row of output contains the `i`th element of each input row. You can't eliminate indexing, because there is no way to iterate over the "columns" implied by the nested list. (Except by using `zip`, which eliminate the need for a separate explicit loop altogether.)

Comment: Yes, it would also require doing `for row in zip(*tableData):` to transpose the rows and columns. Sorry. But regardless using the `join()` would probably be best, as you pointed out at the end in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, you could use join in both, come to think of it: `print(' '.join(row[i] for row in tableData))`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you've got the indexing messed up. Rather than fixing that, it might be better to eliminate the `printTable()` function altogether because you can the whole thing to essentially be reduced to a **single** `print()` call.

This can be done by using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to transpose the rows and columns of the data, along with the string [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to insert whitespace like this:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(item for item in row) for row in zip(*tableData)))
```

Sample output:

```
apples oranges cherries banana 
Alice Bob Carol David 
dogs cats moose goose
```

Comment: It also needs to be `range(len(tableData[0]))` to count columns instead of rows.

Comment: @tdelaney: good point — thanks. The code has been revised to no longer need to do any indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`len(tableData)` is the number of rows in the table. You want the number of columns. Assuming all columns have the same size and the table has at least one row, you can change that to

```
tableData = [["apples","oranges","cherries","banana"],
    ["Alice","Bob","Carol","David"],
    ["dogs","cats","moose","goose"]]

def printTable(table):
    for i in range(len(table[0])):
        for x in table:
            print(x[i], end = " ")
        print()

printTable(tableData)
```

Notice that the function doesn't have a `return`. The caller gets `None` and that's why you get that extraneous line at the end.